# Custom Validation method for non database fields in cakephp 2.3

Tags: validation, cakephp, field

I tried to call custom validation method for non database field in cakephp 2.3 but no luck. The validation method simply is not called. Can some one suggest a fix and explain if this is issue in cake?

my code

```
public $validate = array(
        'name' => array
            (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank'
            ),
        'password' => array
            (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank',
            'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
        'verify_password' => array
            (
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank',
            'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
        'rule2' => array
            (
            'rule' => array('check_password'),
            'message' => 'passwords must match each other',
            'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        ),
       'email' => 'email',
    );
```

where "password" and "verify_passowrd" are non database fields.
custom validation method is

```
function check_password($check) {

        $value = array_values($check);
        $value = $value[0];


         if($value == $this->data['User']['verify_password'])
             return true;
         else 
             return false;

    }
```

Custom method is never ever called.

Comment: Are you sure you copypasted the validate variable correctly? It seems to me that you are missing `array(` just before first rule of verify_password... because this way the rule2 is outside of verify_password and the entire variable isnt even properly ended

Comment: Tip: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ - also note that you should be using last=>true since you are using consecutive validation rules.

Comment: @mark, using last=>true isn't needed: In case of multiple rules per field by default if a particular rule fails error message for that rule is returned and the following rules for that field are not processed. only if you set last=>false it will continue. Simply place the rule you want to be executed first on top.

Comment: @AlexStallen not in 2.x - last=>false is the default here (unfortunately).

Comment: are you sure? I got that piece of information out of the 2.x cookbook

Comment: I was pretty sure about that. It must then have changed recently. If that is the case, then you are right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

First try it add with one rule and then for second one if you wish to test it working or not from your end

here you can check to call your custom function.

```
public $validate = array(
        'password' => array(
            'rule'    => 'check_password',
            'message' => 'Slug can only be letters, numbers, dash and underscore'
        )
    );
```

**Model custom function**

```
function check_password($check) {

    $value = array_values($check);
    $value = $value[0];


     if($value == $this->data['User']['verify_password'])
         return true;
     else 
         return false;
}
```

Please let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: I tried this but still the check_password function is not called.

Comment: Yes when I use the use the custom validation method for database field that work fine.

Comment: is your check_password function is calling at the validation time ?

Answer (score 0):

rule2 is not a field on the form, yet you assign a validation rule to it

if you would ident your code properly you would see errors better

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank'
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank'  
    ),
    'verify_password' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
                    'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                    'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank'
        ),
        'verify' => array(
                    'rule' => array('check_password'),
                    'message' => 'passwords must match each other'
        )
    ),
   'email' => 'email'
);
```

allowEmpty is by false by default and not needed on the notEmpty rule